# Using word "hate" in American English

Tags: speech

Having lived in the USA for several years I've noticed that Americans use the word "hate" a lot. What do they mean? Do they have hate emotion attached when they use this word? Or do they really mean "I don't like" when they say "I hate?" I use the word hate only when I really hate something.

Comment: This is the exact counterpart to *[love](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199627)*, with probably the same answer: these words are used very casually and informally, especially by younger people. If someone says *I hate Mondays*, no, it does not mean they expend emotional energy directing hatred at Monday, which after all is just a day of the week; it simply means someone dislikes that it is Monday. If the English are known for understatement, Americans are known for hyperbole.

Comment: I hate peppermint icecream, and that is true hate in the truest and most literal sense. I hate being in a toilet full of unflushed sanitary urns. I hate having overslept on an appointment. I hate having to hate things I hate. Hate, hate, hate.

Comment: Don't you **hate** it when people do that?

Comment: @choster That is my question about love. :) Nice. I now understand love and hate better in American culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Americans use "hate" and "love" and a variety of other extreme words with little regard to the extremity. It ought to be taken as a declaration of dislike, unless there is particular emotion behind the declaration.

Comment: Indeed.  The latest would be "I literally hate that!" meaning "I mildly dislike it".

Comment: This kind of hyperbole makes me furious!  I'm literally speechless with rage.

Comment: I think there may be a generational component to this as well. In my experience, older people are less likely to use "hate" as a synonym for "dislike."